# How to interpret the red trend map of time series on Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-earth-engine, google-earth, time-series

I'm starting to play with Google Earth Engine. Following https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mNIRB90jwLuASO1JYas1kuOXCLbOoy1Z4NlV1qIXM10/edit# I managet to put together this https://code.earthengine.google.com/625b11fca42309bd7f37159434cd21cf, which generates a time series plot of NDVI. I kind of understand it until the plot.

After that it sets `independents` and `dependent` variables. And computes the `trend` which is added to the map.

[image]

May I ask for help on how to interpret this? What red means?

Answer (score 1):

Play around with the visualization parameters to get a better idea. For example, at the end of your script:

```
Map.addLayer(trend, {min:5,max:10}, 'trend array image; highrange');
Map.addLayer(trend, {min:-5,max:5}, 'trend array image; midrange');
Map.addLayer(trend, {min:-10,max:-5}, 'trend array image; lowrange');
```

Only the "brightest" areas of the midrange set reveal anything informative in the highrange set, suggesting that "bright" regions have a larger positive trend. Similarly, only the "darkest" areas of the midrange set correspond to anything informative in the "lowrange" set, suggesting that darker areas correspond with larger legative trends.